# How to add_menu_page include a php file page from theme directory

Tags: admin-menu

We can add some file in theme folder but it showing in the admin panel.
We can't getting the theme folder file from

```
add_menu_page('Test', 'test', 'manage_options', 'test', 'test.php', null, 6);
```

Comment: Checkout this **https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#comment-2169**

Comment: @PratikPatel Where is located(file path from above tutorial) the custom.php

Answer (score 2):

This is my code to include the file in the theme folder as a page for the admin menu:

```php
// functions.php
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    add_menu_page(
        'Custom Admin Page',
        'Custom Admin Page',
        'manage_options',
        'custom-admin-page',
        function () {
            include dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/admin-settings.php';
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fifth parameter of add_menu_page is of type [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). So you can't just give it "test.php" and expect it to load. But you could probably do something like:

```
// Include the fine with some function for example bananaMonday() declared
include_once( __DIR__ . '/test.php' );

// And then use it as param for add_menu_page
add_menu_page('Test', 'test', 'manage_options', 'test', 'bananaMonday', null, 6);
```

So in the end your full code would be something like this.

**functions.php**

```
function se331925_custom_menu_page() {
    // Include the fine with some function for example bananaMonday() declared
    include_once( __DIR__ . '/test.php' );

    // And then use it as param for add_menu_page
    add_menu_page('Test', 'test', 'manage_options', 'test', 'bananaMonday', null, 6);
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'se331925_custom_menu_page' );
```

**test.php**

```
function bananaMonday() {
    echo '<h1>Hello, it\'s monday';
}
```